Can partial flow separation make the effects of Reynolds number on stall more significant?
While discussing this stall differences with altitude question with a skydiving canopy designer, I told him that most people seemed to think Reynolds would not be significant at these altitudes.
His thought was that it might be different in a canopy, because

Airflow is separated even before stall on a big portion of the canopy. It's specific to [the] way toggle[s] distort the trailing edge.

So...
Can partial flow separation make the effects of Reynolds number on stall more significant?
My thoughts:
I read that lower Reynolds number reduces the stall angle of attack due to increased skin friction. I can't think of how friction would scale differently due to flow separation.
Perhaps Reynolds number could affect the turbulent flow of the separated area?
Or could it simply take less to "tip the stall over the edge" to where it's noticeable?
